# What's the proper way to show/hide a control and let controls next to it take the space?

Tags: delphi, layout, show-hide, vcl

I'm trying to create a dynamic layout with my Delphi VCL application. The normal app should look like this:

[image]

When the user check "Extract extracted files", I need a big button appear under it.

[image]

Now when the user uncheck "Extract extracted files", the app should look like the first image. What's the proper way to implement this kind of layout in Delphi VCL? In some other GUI frameworks, I could use some layout managers to implement this. But in Delphi VCL, I always use anchors. I could calculate control bounds and move them accordingly. But I don't feel it's the right way to do it.

Comment: There are several possibilities: As you say, you can always set positions manually in code (`mNotes.Top := cbExtract.BoundsRect.Bottom + Space`). You could also use a borderless `TPanel` (set `BevelOuter = bvNone`) as a child container below the checkbox, so that the panel occupies the entire space occupied by the memo when it is large. Then you could let the memo be an `Align = alClient` child of this panel, and the button an `Align = alTop` child of the same panel. Set `AlignWithMargins = True` and adjust margins so it looks good. You may also nest panels or use new fancy stuff like...

Comment: ... `TFlowPanel`, `TGridPanel`, `TRelativePanel`, `TStackPanel` etc.

Comment: By the way: You have a very serious bug in your application: The "Files to extract (regex):" label isn't baseline-aligned with its corresponding edit box. :) Also, don't forget to give each control a unique accesskey (`&Search from here:`, `&Browse...`, `&Enable`, etc.) and to make sure that the tab order is correct.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion!